# getting a set of numbers with regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Suppose that I have the folliwing string

```
string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 3/3 "
```

Now, I want to find the set of numbers using regular expressions in Python. Note that the numbers *must* be preceded by `"serial 7's"` I have tried the following:

```
re.findall('(?<=serial 7\'s )(\d+, )', string)
re.findall('(?<=serial 7\'s )(\d+, )+', string)
```

Nothing seems to work. Note that there might be unknown number of integers we are trying to extract. I only want numbers with the specific pattern. Not other numbers that might be scattered within the text.

Expected output: `['93','86','79','72','65']`

Comment: I wish I could accept multiple answers. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents, you could use the below pattern with `re.search`:

```
\bserial 7's\s(\d+(?:-\d+)*)
```

---

```
import re
s = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 3/3 "
res = re.search(r"\bserial 7's\s(\d+(?:-\d+)*)", s)
if res:
    print(res.group(1).split('-')) # ['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
else:
    print('No match')
```

I'd check if any match actually occurs first where the pattern must include numbers which, if there are multiple values, are delimited by an hyphen. Since you mentioned: *"Note that there might be unknown number of integers we are trying to extract. I only want numbers with the specific pattern."*.

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `serial 7's` - Match "serial 7's" literally.
- `\s+` - One or more whitespace characters.
- `(` - Open capture group.
- `\d+` - Match at least a single digit.
- `(?:-\d+)*` - Non-capture group for zero or more times an hyphen followed by at least a single digit.
- `)` - Close capture group.

---

Alternatively one could use `regex` module instead and go with a non-fixed width positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bserial 7's\s+(?:\d+-)*)\d+
```

---

```
import regex
s = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 77 3/3 "
lst = regex.findall(r"(?<=\bserial 7's\s+(?:\d+-)*)\d+", s)
print(lst) # ['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

- `(?<=` - Start of the positive lookbehind.

  - `\b` - A word boudnary.
  - `serial 7's` - Literally "serial 7's".
  - `\s+` - One ore more whitespace characters.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

    - `\d+-` - Match at least a single digit followed by a hyphen.
    - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match it zero or more times.
  - `)` - Close positive lookbehind.
- `\d+` - Match at least a single digit.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it using one regular expression:

```
import re

string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 3/3 "

regex = r"(?<=serial 7's) (\d+-?)+"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    integers = match.group(0).strip().split("-")

print(integers) # ['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `re.findall` here combined with `split`:

```
string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow"
matches = re.findall(r"\bserial 7's (\S+)", string)
nums = matches[0].split('-')
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

Comment: May I know what `\S` represents? I am inclined to accept this answer

Comment: `\S+` will match any continuous collection of non whitespace characters.  In this case, it matches the hyphenated numbers word.

Answer (score 3):

If you can make use of the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could also use `\G` and `\K`

```
(?:\bserial 7's |\G(?!^))-?\K\d+
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bserial 7's`  Match serial 7's and space
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` The `\G` anchor matches at 2 positions: at the beginning of the string, or at the end of the previous match. We don't want the match to start at the beginning, so exclude that using a negative lookahead.
- `)`
- `-?\K` Match optional `-` and reset the match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE5EBn/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##Tc1NC8IgGAfwu5/iyUtKsyBpa0Hs2KGvIIE1twRz41GqQd/dpDp0/r/8xileBy9TsrdxwAhoevMkZNQxGvSwB6Ss2alzMGi1g2oe4KUOrJmdOBeNOqp2QUmIaH2fy/SvVkuxLUVVi2otyg3cDU4Q3PAosnHRzoFcSaCZytvIPu6ys77NEfvxBXyfOU/pDQ)

*Example code*

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:\bserial 7's |\G(?!^))-?\K\d+"
string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 3/3 "

print(regex.findall(pattern, string))
```

*Output*

```
['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try:

```
string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow"

#Simple regex to find numbers
reg = re.compile("\d+")

#We want to find numbers on as short string as possible.
#So, break the long the string into the part we need to search there..
res = reg.findall(s.split("serial 7's")[1])

print(res)
>> ['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

Comment: Your solution will _fail_ should the input string contain numbers other than the ones which appear in the `X-Y-Z` string.

Answer (score 0):

Use PyPi regex and capture the numbers:

```py
import regex  # pip install regex
string = "serial 7's 93-86-79-72-65 very slow, recall 3/3 "
pattern = r"serial\s+7's\s+(?:-?(\d+))+"
match = regex.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    print(match.captures(1))
# ['93', '86', '79', '72', '65']
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEX3/YoJLtoGqtFGoCSGD1EXDVYgQWim9cHX14LO4ixu7skdO/tuGmUI/cNO6AFNaz7EeezHFk6QOIO9HqCgDpQUZS4KJYqDyI/wMjiDG6Z3FqVGDwPInYSEWO29wTHK@LcvLo1@JKsrUbPLLeU8TchD@6Zbasvk1hmNTcf@dga/Fzjp77AWKwLxbAw9W4Nto61/onFszznZwJkqSTOgZb6wUCsPC/MjvYbwBQ)

**Expression explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  serial                   'serial'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  7's                      '7\'s'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```